# How to change the format of Calendar placeholder in Swift UI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

There is code to display the date picker however the date looks in different format then expected

```
 DatePicker( "From date", selection: $endDate, in: closedRange , displayedComponents: [.date]) .padding()
```

It displays like below

[image]

However, the format that I want is  May-01-2022 (MMM-dd-yyyy), But I dont see any swift api to change that.

Comment: You can't you would have to create your own. I might adjust with locale but there are no SwiftUI methods to adjust it.

Comment: strange, any easier way to customize

Comment: SwiftUI Views are meant to be more like "one size fits all" vs "tailor made". Things like formatting are built to adjust with the user's preference/device settings vs how the developer wants it to look. SwiftUI is becoming more custom with every iteration but more often than not a developer that wants to be very specific will have to create their own Views and for even more specificity you will have to use UIKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DatePicker`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/datepicker) uses the date format provided by the [`Locale`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale) stored in the [`locale`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/locale) property of the [`EnvironmentValues`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues). Normally this is the `Locale` provided by iOS based on the user's settings. So it's usually a bad idea to override it.

If you insist on overriding it, you can do so using the [`environment`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/presentedwindowcontent/environment(_:_:)) modifier:

```
DatePicker(blah blah blah)
    .environment(\.locale, someSpecificLocale)
```

Possibly there is a `Locale` that formats the date the way you want. Here's a view that shows all known locales:

```
struct AllLocalesView: View {
    @State var date: Date = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            let locales = Locale.availableIdentifiers
                .map(Locale.init(identifier:))
            ForEach(locales, id: \.identifier) { locale in
                DatePicker(
                    locale.identifier,
                    selection: $date,
                    displayedComponents: .date
                )
                .environment(\.locale, locale)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image: a list in which each row shows a locale identifier and a DatePicker using that locale]

Run that on your system and scroll through the list to see if there's an acceptable `Locale` for your needs.